# Chruszow, Poland,1901

Tags: birth-records, poland, historical-gazetteer, 1900s-decade

I am trying to locate my Grandfather's Birth records. He lists "Chruszow, Poland,1901" as his birthplace.

What would Chruszow, Poland, now be known as? What Parish would I search for Chruszow in? He was Roman Catholic, I apoligise if I have mispelled the name.

[image: Scan of AEF Registration Record]

Answer (score 5):

You need to consult a historical gazetteer of Poland that takes into account the boundary changes with other countries over the years.

https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Poland_Gazetteers is a good starting point to identify a suitable gazetteer. Your document is from 1945 , so you're looking for a relatively recent gazetteer.

I haven't checked in any of the gazetters but http://www.maplandia.com/poland/slaskie/bytom/chruszczow/ might be a contender.

Comment: Thankyou. This is really good info. I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 5):

It does seem that the province shown in your document for both the birthplace and the desired destination is "Śląsk".  That is the polish word for [the Silesia region of Poland](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silesia) which existed between 1742 and 1945. It is located in what now is southern Poland bordering with Germany and the Czech Republic.

[image]

The town is likely [Chorzów](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorz%C3%B3w), which is not shown on the above map but is near Katowice (Kattowitz on the map) near the eastern border of Silesia. 50°18'N 18°58'E, 161 miles SSW of Warsaw.

The destination city in your document appears to be Dziedzice which was also in Śląsk (Silesia), about 20 miles south of Chorzów. It is now known as [Czechowice-Dziedzice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechowice-Dziedzice) following the merger of the two towns in 1951. 49°55'N 19°01'E, 183 miles SSW of Warsaw.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine and should be accepted.

Comment: Silesia is where my family comes from as well

Answer (score -1):

check for Commune Naleczow, lubelskie voivodship.. Found a reference to it in a European Arrest Warrant from a few years ago. It may be where you are looking for.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I will do that now.